# Daily data to monthly average on Python

Tags: python, average

I am really (really) new to Python language and I am having some problems to calculate the monthly average of  a river flow rate using daily data. 
Data example:

```
01/01/1981/;42.989
02/01/1981/;32.093
03/01/1981/;25.334
04/01/1981/;25.334
05/01/1981/;25.767
06/01/1981/;28.868
07/01/1981/;40.925
08/01/1981/;29.777
...
04/02/1981/;27.969
05/02/1981/;27.969
06/02/1981/;29.777
07/02/1981/;30.696
...
29/12/2014/;91.843
30/12/2014/;83.645
31/12/2014/;77.336
```

I would to calculate monthly river flow rate using the daily data.
I also know that packages like numpy or panda do that to, but i need to make this without using them.

```
for row in arq:
    a = row.split(';')
    x = a[0]
    y = float(a[1])
    x = row.split("/" or "/;  ")
    day = int(x[0])
    month = int(x[1])
    year = int(x[2])
    nl.append(y)
    average = sum(nl)/ len(nl)
print(average)
```

So, if you can help I would be really thankful.

Comment: Are you only prohibited from using pandas/numpy, or are _all_ other packages/libraries banned?

Comment: For "monthly average", do you mean for example 2017-Jan, 2018-Jan, 2019-Jan, or do you mean January across all years?

Comment: All the packages are banned

Comment: "monthly average" like 2017-jan, 2017-feb...2017-dec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the variable arq has the required data as rows. Please check the following code:

```
arq_dict={}
for row in arq:
    rlst=row.split(';')
    date=rlst[0]
    val=float(rlst[1])
    month=date[3:]
    if month in arq_dict :
        arq_dict[month].append(val)
    else:
        arq_dict[month]=[val]

for k in arq_dict:
    print("%s;%.3f" %(k,sum(arq_dict[k])/len(arq_dict[k])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a dictionary `monthly_averages` to keep track of the running average for each year/month combination.  It stores the data in a tuple pair, the first value of which is the current average and the second value is the number of observations (needed to update the average for any subsequent data).

Note that `avg observations = sum(observations) / n` where `n` is the number of observations.
Given a new data point, the new average would be `(sum(observations) + new data point) / (n + 1)`. This is then expressed as `(sum(observations) / n * n / (n + 1) + new data point) / (n + 1)`.  Note that `sum(observations) / n` was our prior average, so the new average can thus be expressed as follows:
`new_avg = prior_avg * n / (n + 1) + new data point / (n + 1)`.  Or, more simply: `new_avg = (prior_avg * n + new data point) / (n + 1)`.

I believe the rest of the code is self explanatory, but please let me know if you don't understand any of it and then I'll do my best to clarify.

```
monthly_averages = {}
for row in arq:
    date, daily_rainfall = row.split(';')  # Tuple unpacking.
    day, month, year = date[:-1].split('/')  # Still string format, but that is ok.
    prior_data = monthly_averages.get((year, month))
    if prior_data:
        prior_avg, count = prior_data   # Tuple unpacking.
        new_avg = (prior_avg * count + float(daily_rainfall)) / (count + 1) 
        monthly_averages[(year, month)] = (new_avg, count + 1)
    else:
        monthly_averages[(year, month)] = (float(daily_rainfall), 1)
```

Print the results in a sorted order:

```
for year_month in sorted(monthly_averages):
    print('{}-{}: {:.2f}'.format(*year_month, monthly_averages[year_month][0]))
```